# Can a BIOS password along with a HDD password prevent evil maid attacks?

Tags: bios, physical-access

By definition evil maid attacks involve altering a device in an undetectable way. So if I lock the BIOS, set the HDD to boot first and put a HDD password will this prevent it?

Access to the computer won't be possible as the HDD would be the first to boot and would ask for a password, so no one could try and brute force the BIOS password.And if some one tries to reset the BIOS password then I will find out as it will become clear to me the password has been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an attacker has complete physical access, they could take out your drive, and from another computer, remove the password and access the drive; the ATA password spec may prevent BIOSes from allowing drive access, but there are readily available tools that can simply remove this protection. Even if this feature actually protected the drive, the drive's firmware could be tampered with or replaced, or perhaps the adversary could go to the trouble of putting the disk platters into another drive that is not locked.

Even if they couldn't get the drive to work, maybe they could find a way to install malware into the UEFI/BIOS, or install some hardware keylogger that allows them to enter your passwords at a later time.

To summarize, while this may be effective against a casual intruder, someone with enough time, equipment, and expertise will not be stopped by these protections.

Comment: Or in other words ‘once you got physical access all bets are off’

Comment: Your recent edit addressing the HDD password suggests that the password is in the drive firmware. This is incorrect.

Comment: @user10216038 good call, I had read a source that is clearly inaccurate.

Comment: To install malware on the BIOS they would need to remove the BIOS password first. Is this correct? Thus alerting me that my laptop has been tampered with.

Comment: @Linux_user0987 not necessarily, could depend on things such as vulnerabilities, or hardware access

Comment: @multithr3at3d : If my HDD is set to boot first and supposing they can't access it then they wont be able to boot up an OS to install the bootkit. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Linux_user0987 if the BIOS is overwitten by something malicious, it could still ask for your password (and maybe would accept any password), and then potentially keylog the rest of your passwords or maybe load malicious code at OS boot. You can't defeat hardware compromise like this

Comment: @multithr3at3d : Do you have any idea how long it would take to overwrite the BIOS with something malicious on a laptop? Some laptops are pretty complex to open.  I am asking because I want to know how long it would be safe to leave my laptop alone.

Comment: @multithr3at3d : I see that you didn't answer my last question but can you answer this one? What if the attacker has access to the laptop but cannot open the case? Meaning he can only access the usb slots and the keyboard and mouse also but cannot tamper with the hardware. Can he then in this situation bypass the security measures stated in the question?

Comment: @Linux_user0987 for your first question, it depends how easy the components are to access and whether or not they already know how to attack it, and depends on time, money, and motivation. For the second question, generally no, but there have been low-level vulnerabilities in the near past that could be reached via USB. Look up issues with the Intel Management Engine, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It will raise the bar, requiring a rather talented Evil Maid but it won't entirely prevent it.

First there's **non** HDD related approaches such as a hardware keylogger interfaced with the keyboard, as well as a camera watching you enter the password.

As far as the HDD related approach. The BIOS password becomes irrelevant if I directly attach your HDD to my machine.

The HDD password makes things a good deal trickier. The HDD password is written to a vendor configuration control track not accessible by standard SATA disk commands. The easiest way to get to it is to have the manufacturer's custom interface software that can issue the non-standard commands. In most cases the password is even stored in the clear. There are other ways to do it without the manufacturer's code but it can be slow and tedious.

For better security, look into **UEFI Secure Boot**.

Comment: Why do you think UEFI Secure Boot would help anything? You even mentioned yourself hardware keyloggers.